# Gradle Building Android Project Not using Correct Environment Variable

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm getting this error when building a gradle project that uses the Android SDK:

[image]

And this is what my environment variables look like:

[image]

And my complete PATH environment variable is showing up in the error screen. Why is Gradle not able to find and use just the ANDROID_HOME environment variable?

Comment: I am guessing Gradle looks to the "path" variable to find the sdk. Since you already have a ANDROID_HOME variable, you can easily at that to the end of the path with `.....<other_stuff_on_path>;%ANDROID_HOME%;`

Comment: Yeah I did that. That's why in the error message the last directory is the path to my android home.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, try to "Clean" your project, on Build tab, also run this command in the terminal `gradlew -d assembleDebug`

Comment: I'm currently building the project inside of eclipse with the gradle extension so there is no command line. Should I just build it with the command line outside of eclipse?

Comment: I just ran it with the `assembleDebug` flag. I got spammed with output and error messages but idk what to do with it.

Comment: If your variables are correct declared, you may be able to run te gradle commands in the folder of your project (where must be a folde named .gradle), additionally i would suggest forget eclipse and use the Android Studio

Comment: I need eclipse though because this project is cross-platform, so web and desktop versions are going to be supported alongside android.

Comment: Well, in that case, try to download another SDK and add they to path again, your message of error list all the variables (Power Shell, Phisyx, etc..) i think that is not right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118859/discussion-between-fatal-cubez-and-lucas-queiroz-ribeiro).